# Find user input value and copy/paste another value in an empty field

Tags: vba, excel

I need to locate a date entered by a user in a specific column. If the date is found, the macro should check the third field to the right:

- if it's blank, it should copy and paste a specific value from another sheet;
- if it's not blank, just pop out a message box.

The current code does not do a copy-paste and somehow it is not running through a list of dates though it has been already working before.

```
Sub EnterRecord()
    Dim rcdDate As Date
    Dim r As Range
    Set ws1 = Sheets("Manual")
    Set ws2 = Sheets("Data")
    ws1.Activate
    rcdDate = InputBox("Please enter date dd/mm/yyyy")

    With ws1.Range("K:K")
        Set r = .Cells.Find(What:=rcdDate)
        If Not r Is Nothing Then
            r.Select
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Activate
            If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
                ws2.Range("b1").Copy
                ws1.ActiveCell.Value.Paste Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End If
            MsgBox "Date is incorrect or the record is already entered"    
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Can anyone help in solving the last copy/paste issue (it's just not working at all): ws2.Range("B1).Copy ws1.ActiveCell.Value.Paste Paste:=xlPasteValues

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search for the date in column **K** of *ws1* and you already are using the **With** then replace:

```
Set r = Cells.Find(What:=rcdDate)
```

with

```
Set r = .Cells.Find(What:=rcdDate)
```

There may be other problems.

**EDIT#1**

Once you have executed:

```
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Activate
```

you have "moved" the *ActiveCell*, so replace:

```
If ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = "" Then
```

with

```
If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
```

Comment: Yep! it does the search through the column now, I might have deleted the dot somehow. Many thanks! I only need to get through the copy/paste part now which was never working for me.